# How to find out which if page was previously allocated when reading process memory

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a program that reads the memory of other processes. This seems quite straightforward however I came across one problem. If the process I'm trying to read from has memory mapped but it has not use that memory so far (e.g. process called malloc, but never read from or wrote to that memory) the physical pages are not yet allocated. I presume this is the lazy allocation.

Now, when my program tries to read that memory it's immediately allocated. I would like to avoid that as I noticed some programs seems to allocate (or map) very large amounts that they don't normally use. This either causes very large memory consumption after the read or, in extreme cases, the process even being killed by OOM as the mapped region was bigger than the available ram. This is of course not acceptable as my reader should ideally be transparent and not affect the process being examined.

So far I just found information about `/proc/pid/pagemap` but I'm not fully sure if it suits my needs. There is a 'present' bit but I did not found information what it exactly means and if this is what I'm looking for.

Can someone confirm that? Or there's another way of achieving the same goal.

Comment: Looks right https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt

Comment: Unfortunately pagemap.txt is not very descriptive when it comes to this.  For example, it says `Unmapped pages return a null PFN` -- but `PFN` is only valid if the present bit is set, so this implies that the present bit is not sufficient to determine if the page is mapped...